# How to use for each loop in java if there has multiple datatypes in an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, collections, foreach

How to use for each loop in java if there has multiple datatypes in an array?

My code so far:

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
al.add("Ravi");
al.add("Vijay");
al.add("Ravi");
al.add("Ajay");
al.add(123);
al.add(456);

for(??? obj: al)
```

Comment: now edited. can u check and help

Comment: Why not `Object`?

Comment: [Don't use raw types!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Something else: It is not an _array_. It is an `ArrayList`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Object` type:

```
for (Object obj:al){}
```

Comment: Thanks. its running but iam getting following message in console            
 :java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Comment: That is a warning and not an error so the code will still compile. Let me check what I get and get back to you

Comment: All the warnings I got were just saying to parameterize the generic type of the `ArrayList` which went away by parametrizing when initializing it like: `ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<Object>();`

Comment: Thanks @priyaraj . now its not showing any warnings

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here: step back and **learn** about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

The various issues you are facing are caused by one simple thing: you have not much clue of what you are doing.

First of all, you were using a **[raw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)** type (by not providing a type parameter to your list). Ideally, lists are used like this:

```
List<Whatever> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your case, Whatever should be `Object`.

But then: your idea of having different things in the same list might already be *bad* practice. You see, collections are providing you generics, to explicitly say: "I have a list of X". And then you can be assured that only X objects are in that list.

In other words: having `List<Object>` is something that you normally want to avoid. You **want** that the compiler helps you to understand what kind of objects you have in that list!

Comment: thank you. you are absolutely right .i am new to collections as unaware of many things that needs to be learn.